# Show that $(50)^{\frac{3}{4}} * (\frac{5}{\sqrt 2})^{\frac{-1}{2}} = 10$

Tags: proof-writing, roots

I can't solve the following task

> Show that $(50)^{\frac{3}{4}} * (\frac{5}{\sqrt 2})^{\frac{-1}{2}} = 10$

The book provides the following solution to this problem

> $(50)^{\frac{3}{4}} * (\frac{5}{\sqrt 2})^{\frac{-1}{2}} = (2.5^2)^{\frac{3}{4}} * (5.2^{\frac{-1}{2}})^{\frac{-1}{2}}= 2^{\frac{3}{4}}*5^{\frac{3}{2}}*5^{\frac{-1}{2}}*2^{\frac{1}{4}} = 10$

Could you please explain the following solution to me ?

1. Why is $50 = 2.5^2$ ? Same for 2.5.

Comment: $\cdot$ means multiplication.

Comment: Actually, the dot should be places at the center of text , not the bottom. It’s mean multiplication. Like @fleablood have said in the previous comment.

Comment: Yes, seems like a book had an error. The textbook is "A concise introduction to Pure Mathematics " Martin Liebeck.

Comment: Some typesetters will set it $2.5$ meaning $2\cdot 5$.  Drives me nuts but it's not uncommon.  It's more common in europe in countrys which use commas as decimal points so it's less likely the reader will confuse it as a decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cdot$ means multiplication.

Would it be clearer if it read as:

> $(50)^{\frac{3}{4}} \cdot (\frac{5}{\sqrt 2})^{\frac{-1}{2}} = (2\cdot5^2)^{\frac{3}{4}} \cdot (5\cdot2^{\frac{-1}{2}})^{\frac{-1}{2}}= 2^{\frac{3}{4}}\cdot5^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot5^{\frac{-1}{2}}\cdot2^{\frac{1}{4}} = 10$

?

Answer (score 0):

The solution by saying $$(50=2.5^2)$$ means: $$50=(5^2)×(2)=25×2$$
The dot represents multiply.
If any other part is unclear mention.

Answer (score 0):

It's $$\frac{\sqrt[4]{50^3}}{\sqrt\frac{5}{\sqrt2}}=\sqrt[4]{\frac{50^3\cdot2}{25}}=\sqrt[4]{\frac{5^6\cdot2^4}{5^2}}=10.$$